# dependent muti select drop down in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal , in my project I have 2  multiple select drop down box. I don't know how to do dependent multi select drop down action in drupal form alter function using ajax.

Single selection dependent drop down selection is working. But when i tried the same in case of 2 multi select dependent drop down i couldn't find any solution . On multi select error "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator." is shown.

Please help me how to use 2 multi select dependent drop down in drupal.

Here is my code :  here "field_department" is the 1st multi select drop down. "field_policy_categories" is the 2nd muti select drop down. i want 2nd drop down values corresponding to 1st field's multi selected options.

```
if ($form_id == 'policy_node_form') {
    $category = array();
    $category[''] = '- None -'; 

    $form['field_department']['und']['#ajax'] = array(         
        'wrapper' => 'policy_category_list',
        'callback' => 'ajax_policy_category_callback',
        'method' => 'replace',
    );

    $form['field_policy_categories']['#validated'] = TRUE;
    $form['field_file_upload']['#validated'] = TRUE;

    if (isset($form_state['values']['field_department'])) {            

        $array_departments = array($form_state['values']['field_department']['und']['0']['tid']);

        $query = db_select('field_data_field_department', 'f');
        $query->join('taxonomy_term_data', 't', 'f.entity_id = t.tid');
        $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'h', 't.tid = h.tid');

        $query->condition('f.entity_type', 'taxonomy_term', '=');
        $query->condition('f.bundle', 'policy_categories', '=');            
        $query->condition('f.field_department_tid', $array_departments, 'IN');
        $query->condition('h.parent', 0, '=');
        $query->fields('f');
        $query->fields('t');
        $query->fields('h');
        $result = $query->execute();

        $policy_vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('policy_categories')->vid;

        $category[''] = '- None -';

        foreach ($result as $record) {
            $parent_arr = taxonomy_get_parents_all($record->tid);
            $parent_level = sizeof($parent_arr);
            $parent_level--;
            $parent_tid = $parent_arr[$parent_level]->tid;
            $parent_name = $parent_arr[$parent_level]->name;
            $category[$parent_tid] = $parent_name;

            $policy_children_arr = taxonomy_get_tree($policy_vid, $parent_tid);
            foreach ($policy_children_arr as $key => $policy_children) {
                $depth = '';
                for ($i = $policy_children->depth; $i >= 0; $i--)
                    $depth .= '--';
                $category[$policy_children->tid] = $depth . $policy_children->name;
            }
        }

        $form['field_policy_categories']['und']['#options'] = $category;
    } else {

        $form['field_policy_categories']['und']['#options'] = $category;
    }

    $form['field_policy_categories']['#prefix'] = '<div id="policy_category_list">';
    $form['field_policy_categories']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['#validate'][] = 'form_validate_policy_add';
}

function ajax_policy_category_callback($form, &$form_state) {

    return $form['field_policy_categories'];
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Can you suggest any other method for dependent multiple selection drop down select box in drupal 7.